# How do I handle this "broken packages" problem with Nvidia 465 on Mint 19?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

So, Mint 19 surprised me in the update manager with Nvidia's 465 driver, and I attempted to install it; but all it did (it's hard to tell if it even downloaded anything) was inform me that it "Could not apply changes! Fix broken packages first."

[image: pop-up error]

There is, concerningly, no note on which package is broken, and I don't have anything that Synaptic is aware of being broken. I haven't restarted my system yet, as I have no idea if my current drivers are still viable.

Attempting to do it by apt tells me that a number of packages have been "kept back"; though interestingly, they all end in 455.

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnvidia-cfg1-455 libnvidia-common-455 libnvidia-compute-455
  libnvidia-compute-455:i386 libnvidia-decode-455 libnvidia-decode-455:i386
  libnvidia-encode-455 libnvidia-encode-455:i386 libnvidia-extra-455
  libnvidia-fbc1-455 libnvidia-fbc1-455:i386 libnvidia-gl-455
  libnvidia-ifr1-455 libnvidia-ifr1-455:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-455
  nvidia-kernel-common-455 nvidia-kernel-source-455
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
```

I can only assume that something has gone terribly awry with my package organization, but I really don't know what it is or how to fix it. I'm hoping someone can shed a little light on this for me. I haven't ever installed a driver on this machine in a non-apt way, and it's a rarity for me to actually have a broken package to begin with.

Attempting to manually install the above packages gives me this.

```
$ sudo apt install libnvidia-cfg1-455 libnvidia-common-455 libnvidia-compute-455 libnvidia-compute-455:i386 libnvidia-decode-455 libnvidia-decode-455:i386 libnvidia-encode-455 libnvidia-encode-455:i386 libnvidia-extra-455 libnvidia-fbc1-455 libnvidia-fbc1-455:i386 libnvidia-gl-455 libnvidia-ifr1-455 libnvidia-ifr1-455:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-455 nvidia-kernel-common-455 nvidia-kernel-source-455 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-kernel-common-455 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-465 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-kernel-source-455 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-465 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is especially weird to me, as it implies that 455 depends on 465, which shouldn't have existed yet to begin with.

Comment: Update: After switching my driver to an earlier version, canceling, and switching back to 260, suddenly everything seems to be fine... I personally doubt it, but this has made this a low-priority issue for me. If I continue to have good luck again over the next few days, I'll delete this. I'm just **really** trying not to have to reinstall my graphics card driver from scratch...

Comment: were your nvidia packages marked as *held*?   run `dpkg -l '*nvidia*' | grep '^h'`.   if they are held, you can un-hold them with `apt-mark unhold pkg1 pkg2 pkg3 ... pkgN`.   Note: there are other nvidia-related packages that don't have "nvidia" in the package name - `libvdpau1` and `libcuda1`, for example. If you have them installed, make sure they're not held too.   In case this happens to be the problem, I'll add an answer with the trivial script I use to manage nvidia versions on my debian boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# script: list-nvidia.sh
# author: Craig Sanders <cas@taz.net.au>
# license: Public Domain (this script is too trivial to be anything else)

# options:
# default/none    list the packages, one per line
# -v              verbose (dpkg -l) list the packages
# -h              hold the packages with apt-mark
# -u              unhold the packages with apt-mark

# build an array of currently-installed nvidia packages.
PKGS=( $(dpkg -l '*nvidia*' '*cuda*' '*vdpau*' 2>/dev/null |
           awk '/^[hi][^n]/ && ! /mesa/ {print $2}') )

case "$1" in
  "-v") dpkg -l "${PKGS[@]}" ;;
  "-h") apt-mark hold "${PKGS[@]}" ;;
  "-u") apt-mark unhold "${PKGS[@]}" ;;
  *) printf "%s\n" "${PKGS[@]}" ;;
esac
```

This script can list installed nvidia-related packages one per line, or in verbose `dpkg -l` format.

It can also use `apt-mark` to hold and unhold the nvidia packages - I use these options immediately before and immediately after `apt-get dist-upgrade` to ensure that the nvidia driver only gets upgraded when **I** want it to (i.e. when I'm ready to reboot my system, or kill and restart X).

The plain listing (with `printf`) is useful if I want to do other things with the list, like use it in a command substitution -- e.g. `apt purge $(list-nvidia.sh)`.  Debian package names will never have spaces or newlines etc in them, so there's no need to be paranoid about quoting.

Comment: The problem hasn't resurfaced yet; but next it shows its face I'll give this script a go. Thank you. What's vdpau, though?

Comment: VDPAU = Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix.   hardware acceleration of video playback.